# Is there a way to interpolate attribute values out of the box with i18n and Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, internationalization

I'm trying to present better validation error messages to users. For example, a given uniqueness validation message says something along the lines of:

> Student is already enrolled in this course

However, I want it to say:

> Student **Leroy Jenkins** is already enrolled in **Calculus II**

The reason is because I have a nested form that created many `students_courses` at the same time, so the user may see half a dozen of these messages and they won't know which students are invalid.

Does ActiveRecord provides us with any option to automatically get the model's attributes for interpolation? Something like `%{model.student.name}`? If not, I already know how to manually pass parameters for interpolation, I'm just asking if there's a better way to do it.

Btw, it must use i18n, as we have to support more than 1 language.

---

The error message above was placed in the `en.yml` file under this structure:

```
activerecord:
  errors:
    models:
      students_courses:
        taken: "is already enrolled in this course"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you can use for error-message-interpolation can be seen in this documentation: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-interpolation

for your use-case this means no, you don't get to play with the model here. what you actually get is `value` in your case that would be the id of the course i guess.

but it should not be that bad, you could adapt the logic of the [UniquenessValidator](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0d73d6e7b6dd1900f105397460b777ef6c03d3b6/activerecord/lib/active_record/validations/uniqueness.rb#L34) by creating a new or similar one and using that for your validations.